# What would a Cayley table of inverse semigroup look like?

Tags: group-theory, inverse, monoid, cayley-table, finite-semigroups

I tried to construct a Cayley table of an algebraic structure called inverse semigroup. No success so far. I just end up with more complicated structure (monoid, group). Thank you kindly.

I may think, that this phrasing is more accurate and more to the point.
Also, I have checked many sources and didn't find an example...

One possibility would be, that it is not possible (which I doubt). Or why would it be not possible?

One chance is to try for any set $X$, let $I(X)$ be the set of all partial bijections on $X \to X$, i.e. bijections between subsets of $X \to X$. The composite of partial bijections is their composite as relations (or as partial functions). In fact, any inverse semigroup is isomorphic to a sub-inverse-semigroup.

Comment: If this is so simple, kindly please show me the table :)

Comment: It is very easy to create semigroup, but to ensure inversion is difficult (at least for me). Inversion is not simply just inversion to identity. But some kind of cancellation property or aba=a, bab=b construction. Internet is full of words but no pictures. I hope that now my question is clear. I hope someone knows the answer.

Comment: I know, these are used as synonyms in my country :)

Comment: I don't seek greater structure (monoid, group), I seek to create purely inverse semigroup, withou identity (no monoid). It seems to me that no one knows. Just all people beat around the bush, trying to be smart.
With 2 elements (0,1) it is impossible to create purely inverse semigroup...you end up with other structure.

Comment: If you are asking for an example of an inverse semigroup that is not a monoid, you should state it explicitly in your question. I also encourage you to delete your arrogant comments.

Comment: I believe it is abundantly clear in description. However my math skills are not so advanced, I am aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned yourself, the set of all partial bijections on a set $X$ is an inverse monoid. If you take the set of all partial bijections that are not bijective, you get an inverse semigroup that is not a monoid. For instance, if $X$ is a two-element set, you get the five element Brandt semigroup. It can also be described as the semigroup
$$
S = \{a, b, ab, ba, 0\}
$$
generated by $a$ and $b$ under the relations $aba = a$, $bab = b$ and $aa = bb = 0$.
Up to the identity, this example was given to you in a comment that you ignored and was deleted by his author. Your example is the same, in a more complicated presentation, since you use a set with $5$ elements instead of just $2$.

Another description of the semigroup is
$$
S = \left\{\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}, \pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}, \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}, \pmatrix{0&0\\0&0} \right\}
$$
a description (again up to the identity) that was also given in a comment that you ignore.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem! :)

I found a structure and table which is pure inverse semigroup and it table.
So solution all other similar questions is this. Behold:

> '...1 2 3 4 5

> 1...1 1 1 1 1

> 2...1 2 3 1 1

> 3...1 1 1 2 3

> 4...1 4 5 1 1

> 5...1 1 1 4 5

I dont know how to type table :)
But: no identity!, Associativity proved by Light's test :), even not commutative, and
iverse by definitions aba=a, bab=b. Inverses are: a-a, b-b, c-d, d-c, e-e!!! I am so happy.

This is pure inverse semigroup!